# Views "Load More" replacing results instead of appending

Tags: views, theming

Views load more is replacing the results rather than appending those below the existing ones.

I am using block for content listing and need a append more option to load more content below the existing one. I tried views show more and views load more extensions.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [Views Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) module.

> Views infinite scroll allows you to load and display pages of any view
>   inline, using AJAX (this has been called infinite scrolling, load
>   more, autopaging, endless pages and more). The pager can be triggered
>   with the press of a button or automatically as the user scrolls to the
>   bottom of the view's content.

Comment: Yes I tried this extension as well but it didn't work

Comment: It does work @KaustubhBhagwat, I use it on a bunch of different sites

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to add `.view-content` in Advanced Options, see the attached screenshot.

Not sure it is a bug or not, when I put that it starts working as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [GD Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/gd_infinite_scroll) module.  Does exactly what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Views Load More" and set "Use AJAX" option to Yes under Advanced view settings.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same issue, and it appears that [views_infinite_scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) will replace, rather than append, if you have theme_debug on. i.e. `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;`. Turning this off returned it to its normal append behavior.